# A space in JSON value causes "unexpected token END OF FILE at position 11" exception when parsing in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

When I use the parser from org.json.simple.parser.* I get an exception whenever one of the values in JSON contains a space. For example:

```
{"name":"Adam"}
```

would parse correctly, but

```
{"name":"Ad am"}
```

would cause "unexpected token END OF FILE at position 11" exception

Here is the code that I use to convert a JSON string into a JSONObject.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get through this below example and each value contains `space` except `integer` one and giving this example just because of you don't have shared your source code.

JSON File(`personal_detail.json`):

```
{
    "name":"arif mustafa",
    "age":26,
    "address":["district is Korba","state is Chhattisgarh","country is India"]
}
```

`Java` source to read the `JSON` file format:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JSONExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/resources/personal_detail.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonObject + "\n");

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            System.out.println("name : " + name);

            long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
            System.out.println("age : " + age);

            //get Object loop array
            JSONArray address = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("address");
            System.out.println("address is : ");

            Iterator<String> iterator = address.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry copied it wrong into the question :facepalm: - now corrected

Comment: @kyczawon Ohhhh! post the questions correctly, and have a review before posting it.

Comment: @kyczawon try to get help through this modified answer, and obligate to answer you because I have given the first answer, be specific and clear *next time!*